# Set static ip for every docker container in my home LAN

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, webmin

I need my docker containers to have a static ip addreses in my lan, so i could access them by unique ip.

I've tried to do this with network, but this did not worked.
This is example of docker-compose file i've tried:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
   postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.241:5432:5432"
    depends_on:
      - webmin
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: openfire
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    networks:
      - docker-lab

  webmin:
    image: 'chsliu/docker-webmin'
    container_name: webmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.242:10000:10000"
      - "192.168.1.242:53:53/tcp"
      - "192.168.1.242:53:53/udp"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: openfire
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    networks:
      - docker-lab

networks:
  docker-lab:
    driver: bridge
```

When i'm running it with `docker-compose -f lab.yml up -d` - i'm getting this error:

```
Creating webmin ... 
Creating webmin ... error

ERROR: for webmin  Cannot start service webmin: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webmin (02633ecc5adf4506bb7217472527cea7a4a3a7ef94d5181ebacc1ff6721c5d93): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.1.242:10000: bind: cannot assign requested address

ERROR: for webmin  Cannot start service webmin: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webmin (02633ecc5adf4506bb7217472527cea7a4a3a7ef94d5181ebacc1ff6721c5d93): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.1.242:10000: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

#### Docker version:

`Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b`
`docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown`

#### System:

```
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="37 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=37
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f37"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition)"
```

Comment: How do you assign IP addresses to other individual processes on your host?  Have you assigned the mentioned addresses on 192.168.1.0/24 to a host interface already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved this task

First i've created virtual interfaces:

`ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.241 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

`ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.242 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

Then i've just runned my docker-compose file without a network configuration but with ip's binded to containers. Example:

```yaml
postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      #Binding port to IP (ip:port:port)
      - "192.168.1.241:5432:5432"
    depends_on:
      - webmin
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: openfire
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

[This post on edureka](https://www.edureka.co/community/13036/expose-docker-container-port-outside-docker-without-mapping) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two virtual IP with that specified IP

/etc/systemd/network/vip1.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=vip1
Kind=dummy
```

/etc/systemd/network/vip2.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=vip2
Kind=dummy
```

/etc/systemd/network/vip1.network

```
[Match]
Name=vip1

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.241
Mask=255.255.255.0
Broadcast=192.168.1.255
```

/etc/systemd/network/vip2.network

```
[Match]
Name=vip2

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.242
Mask=255.255.255.0
Broadcast=192.168.1.255
```

Then restart network service

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

Finally run your compose again

```
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: This worked but ip is only available on machine which running this container. Also SSH does not available anymore

Comment: I do not understand what you said `but ip is only available on machine which running this container`! you cannot assign your home lan IP to container directly, you must do this way and expose your port on virtual ip. Do you want to ssh 192.168.1.241-242 ?

Comment: No. I don't want SSH on container. I need it only on my server which running this containers.

Comment: I need to have an access to this containers in my LAN by their own ip's, not by ip of server.